# Create an orientated Quad in Eigen C++ library

Tags: c++, 3d, geometry, eigen, eigen3

I'm a newbie that is driving nuts with a really simple problem :\ How to define a quad that has its center at position x=10 y=11 z=12 with side 5 and it is facing at camera.

My naive implementation:

```
Eigen::Vector3f quadPosition(10, 11, 12);
Eigen::Vector3f camPos(10, 5, 12);
float sideLength = 5;
Eigen::Affine3f transform = Eigen::Translation3f(position) * Eigen::AngleAxisf(3.141595, (camPos - quadPosition).normalized());

Eigen::Vector3f v0 = transform * Eigen::Vector3f(-sideLength / 2, -sideLength / 2, 0);
Eigen::Vector3f v1 = transform * Eigen::Vector3f(sideLength / 2, -sideLength / 2, 0);
Eigen::Vector3f v2 = transform * Eigen::Vector3f(sideLength / 2, sideLength / 2, 0);
Eigen::Vector3f v3 = transform * Eigen::Vector3f(-sideLength / 2, sideLength / 2, 0);

Eigen::MatrixXd verts;
verts.resize(4, 3);
verts(0, 0) = v0(0);
verts(0, 1) = v0(1);
verts(0, 2) = v0(2);
verts(1, 0) = v1(0);
verts(1, 1) = v1(1);
verts(1, 2) = v1(2);
verts(2, 0) = v2(0);
verts(2, 1) = v2(1);
verts(2, 2) = v2(2);
verts(3, 0) = v3(0);
verts(3, 1) = v3(1);
verts(3, 2) = v3(2);
Eigen::MatrixXi faces;
faces.resize(2, 3);
faces(0, 0) = 0;
faces(0, 1) = 1;
faces(0, 2) = 2;
faces(1, 0) = 0;
faces(1, 1) = 2;
faces(1, 2) = 3;
```

Any idea? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

One common approach is to define the quad in terms of two opposed corners  like: `[0,0,0]` and `[1,1,1]`. Now you know that anything in between 0 and 1 in `X`, `Y` and `Z` axis belong to the box ... as long as there is no rotation. Otherwise, you could also add it.